# FadeIn jquery [not working]

Tags: jquery, menu, fadein, jsfiddle

I am new at jquery and my fadeIn is not working. I made a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YGB5G/46/) here. Thank you

```js
$('#menu > li').on('mouseover', function(e){
  $(this).find("ul:first").fadeIn(120).finish();
  $(this).find('> a').addClass('active');
}).on('mouseout', function(e){
  $(this).find("ul:first").stop().finish().delay(500).fadeOut(120);
  $(this).find('> a').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.finish()`:

```
$('#menu > li').on('mouseover', function(e){
  $(this).find("ul:first").fadeIn(120);
  $(this).find('> a').addClass('active');
}).on('mouseout', function(e){
  $(this).find("ul:first").stop().finish().delay(500).fadeOut(120);
  $(this).find('> a').removeClass('active');
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/YGB5G/47/

From [jQuery site](https://api.jquery.com/finish/):

> When .finish() is called on an element, the currently-running animation and all queued animations (if any) immediately stop and their CSS properties set to their target values. All queued animations are removed.

Comment: Thank you! It works but when I stay on the menu the delay keeps looping

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: I want when I hover to fadeIn the menu. And when the mouse leave the menu to start a delay and then fadeOut.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. Can the menu not show again when I quickly leave the menu and enter it?

Comment: Sure, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/YGB5G/49/. Also consider make this with CSS transitions in future or if you have some time.